# Ruby gems repository

Tags: ruby, repository, rubygems

I'm trying to set a gem repository on one of our local servers.  Here are the steps I'm running, that I've followed from several guides.

1) I create the *BASEDIR* folder */var/www/html/gems*
2) sudo cp -r /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/someGem  /var/www/html/gems
3) sudo gem generate_index -d /var/www/html/gems

However, when I run this, I get the following output:

```
Loading 0 gems from /var/www/html/gems

Loaded all gems
Generating quick index gemspecs for 0 gems

Complete
Generating specs index
Generating latest specs index
Generating quick index
Generating latest index
Generating Marshal master index
Generating YAML master index for 0 gems (this may take a while)

Complete
Compressing indicies
```

It's not loading the gem for some reason.  I did see a guide that recommended making the *BASEDIR* as */var/www/html/rubygems/* and then further make a *gems/* directory within the *BASEDIR* and copy the desired gems to this *gems/* directory.  I also tried this, but was getting the same results.

Our server had the unfortunate luck of having the same configuration as mentioned in this [post](http://rambleon.org/2007/12/03/your-own-gem-server-and-ruby-185/) (RHEL5, ruby 1.8.5, /var and /tmp on separate partitions), but we upgraded as suggested to ruby 1.8.6, but it still won't load the gem.

Has anyone come across this?  Found a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I stumbled upon my old post and realized I'd actually solved this some time ago, so I figured I'd post my answer.

The problem was my step 2: copy gems action.

In the OP, I had tried

> 2) sudo cp -r /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/someGem /var/www/html/gems

What I found was that I needed to copy the actual *.gem* files, which lived at .../gems/1.8/gems/**cache**  .  So what I really needed to do for step 2 is:

```
sudo cp .../gems/1.8/gems/cache/*.gem /var/www/html/gems
```

After copying the gems correctly, the indexing worked as expected, and we could then use our server by adding it as a gem source on various machines.  Installing our custom gems then worked smoothly.

Answer (score 5):

We internally use [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/RubyGems+Repository) for managing our in-house rubygems - some of them are proprietary and some are publicly released. we can enforce security between our different groups (dev, qa - prerelease, release, ...)

Also, [rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org) is proxied and cached locally, which helps us gain better performance and avoid remote downtimes.

Eventually, developers are using a single source url, aggregating both remote and local repositories transparently.

Answer (score 4):

You should generate the index not on the gems subdirectory. But on the basedir one.

```
sudo gem generate_index -d /var/www/html
```

It'll take automatically the gems in the "gems" subdirectory.
And generate the index at in the basedir.

Comment: OK, in this situation, where would I copy the gems to then...?

Comment: You would have the gems in the "gems" subdirectory.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your original reply as "It'll MAKE automatically..."  Anyway, it still doesn't work...  Maybe our unlucky configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me so I started to browse the code for Gem::Indexer and wrote a few lines of code to do the indexing from irb launched from my host destination (the one above ./gems):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rubygems/indexer'

i=Gem::Indexer.new '.'
i.generate_index
```

And if you want to update the index later:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rubygems/indexer'

i=Gem::Indexer.new '.'
i.update_index
```

I suspect the issue with the gem command must exist somewhere higher at the command parsing level but I have not looked into it (I just wanted to create my repository and move on).